# Trouble with regular expressions in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to check given logical formulars with a regular expression.
The logical connectives for this form are & (and) , | (or), (!) negation sign (multiple negations allowed) and the variables are normal character sequences followed with cardinalities [0],[1],[0..1].
the variable names can also something be like this "F.G.H." or "F:G:H:" or simple "F" etc. 
the square brackets belongs to the cardinalites.,lso constants are allowed, 
e.g. 
with this pattern it is not working:

`Pattern.compile("([!]*[a-zA-Z][\\.])?([!]*[a-zA-Z][\\.]?)*((\\[0\\])?|(\\[1\\])?|(\\[0\\.\\.1\\])?)|(TRUE)|(FALSE)|(&)|(|)|(!)");` 
my current case that a variable like this: !!F[0] is not accepted, but i want this to be accepted.

here some examples for the formulars, which i want to allow

!!F[0] & !F1.G[0..1] | (F1[1] | F2[0]) & F:G[0..1]

also whitespaces between each element, except variables and their cardinalities shall be allowed.

Comment: Are you sure that a regex is the best way to go? It seems to me you want to parse the expression anyway, so your parser can throw an error if the expression is invalid.

Comment: i thought it would be the best way, better than many if statements for the single characters. I think using regular expressions is quite an elegant way to achieve this

Comment: also if iam parsing the formula, i have to parse each char element, so it could be difficult to ensure that some like this |.& is not allowed...the original type of the formular is a string object

Comment: You seem to have parenthetical expressions in your desired allowed state. Are nested parenthetical expressions allowed? If so then a regex is probably not the answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns

Comment: @lunatikz, If you want to check if a formula is valid or not, or even worse evaluate it, you must write a parser, e.g. http://www.antlr.org/  http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/

Answer (score 1):

This one <strike>is quite awful but</strike> should suit your needs:

```
[!(]*([A-Z]+[0-9]*([.:][A-Z]+[0-9]*)*\[([01]|0[.]{2}1)\]|TRUE|FALSE)[)]*( *[&|] *[!(]*([A-Z]+[0-9]*([.:][A-Z]+[0-9]*)*\[([01]|0[.]{2}1)\]|TRUE|FALSE)[)]*)*
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com?3501o)

Please note that is simply *allows* parentheses without *counting* them, i.e. inputs such as `!((!(F[0])` will match while only `!((!(F[0])))` should.

---

If you want something already cleaner, you could *build* your regex *step by step*:

```java
String atomVarPref = "[!(]*";
String atomVar = "[A-Z]+[0-9]*";
String atomSep = "[.:]";
String atomVarCard = "\\[([01]|0[.]{2}1)\\]";
String atomVarSuff = "[)]*";
String sep = " *[&|] *";

String varTemplate = "%s(%s(%s%s)*%s|TRUE|FALSE)%s";
String var = String.format(varTemplate, atomVarPref, atomVar, atomSep, atomVar, atomVarCard, atomVarSuff);

String regexTemplate = "%s(%s%s)*";
String regex = String.format(regexTemplate, var, sep, var);
```

Calling:

```java
String input = "!!F[0] & !F1.G[0..1] | (F1[1] | F2[0]) & F:G[0..1]";
System.out.println(input.matches(regex)); // prints true
```